# Create spectogram plot with different length of x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am currently working with a project in which in which i need to use spectograms of audio file.

I am currently using a different program to generate the power spectrum of an audio file, and plot it using matplotlib, as such:

```
for elements in file_names_data_start_end_index:
    ## Entries = Rows of the output data
    ## Length  = Columns of the output data
    entries = elements[2] - elements[1]+1
    name = elements[0]
    length = data_splitted[elements[1]].count(" ")-2
    print "Filename: " + name + " Entries: " + str(entries) +  " Length: "  + str(length)
    output = ""
    for i in range(elements[1],elements[2]+1):
        output += data_splitted[i]
        #print data_splitted[i]
    #print output[:-1]
    output = np.fromstring(output[:-1],count=-1,sep=' ')
    #output_log = np.log(output)
    output_reshaped = output.reshape(entries,length)
    #print output_reshaped.shape
    ##Do the actual plot!
    # 1 second audio creates 98 rows, as there is a overlap on 10 ms will
    # extra data be created, normally would it have been 16000/512 = 31 rows
    # if the frames where disjoint, but not in this case. 160 samples is the extra overlap.
    # (16000-512)/160+1 = 97.8 ~ 98
    Y =  np.array(range(0,length)) * (16000.0/512.0)
    X =  np.array(range(0,entries))*(1/98.0)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    #print type(X)
    #print type(Y)
    #print type(output_reshaped)
    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,output_reshaped.T,  cmap=cm.jet)
    #surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,output_reshaped)
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
    plt.title('Power spectrum of ' + name)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig(spectogram+"test_spect_plots/"+name+"_plot.png")
    plt.close()
    print "Saved"
```

Problems with this, is that the plot i always has the same size, even though the audio file is timewize longer or shorter...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liUip.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uzv.png)

The resolution of the time axis is not fixed, is there a way to keep it fixed such that matplotlib don't try to fit the image to a prefixed size, but just extend the x-axis and make the plot a bit longer?

Comment: You can set the x-axis size using `plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)`. See the [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) for details.

Comment: instead of      `X =  np.array(range(0,entries))*(1/98.0)`

Comment: Nope. It looks like X is your x-values. You'll need those for plotting your data. Just add `plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)` on a line somewhere (e.g. just after `plt.title`) and specify `xmin` and `xmax` either by defining them as variables or plugging in your desired minimum and maximum x-axis values.

Comment: Ahh.. I see.. Yes. that should do it!